# for loop using tsCV - error in NextMethod("[<-") : replacement has length zero

Tags: r, for-loop, time-series, forecasting

I'm fairly new to R and trying to evaluate a forecast on tbats using the tsCV function in a for loop. Unfortunately with out luck.

The code that I'm passing is:

```
e <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow = 68, ncol = 8) 
{
for (i in 1:8) 
 e[i] <- tsCV(mth2, forecastfunction = tbats, h = i)
}
```

The data that i'm using is of class ("ts") time serie and looks like this

```
          Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug
2017 143128.4 112529.8 119132.7 112265.9 109958.2 121764.8
```

The error that it throws me looks like this:

```
error in NextMethod("[<-") : replacement has length zero
```

I have tried many things but cannot solve it.

Comment: `tbats` does not return a forecast object. Check the help file.

Comment: @RobHyndman - Thank you, appriciate your work. I created the function 'tb <- function(x, h){forecast(tbats(mth2), h=h)} ' and that made it running. I do have monthly data and 68 observations, running the loop takes a lot of time, approx. 30 min for h=1:8. Any ideas on how to improve the speed, or does this process normally take a long time when processing.